# Stored Procedure in SQL Server Studio to get last ten years

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

> I know its probably an easy question but I am trying to create a stored procedure to get the last ten years from a table in my database so that I can then show them on my View in an MVC asp.net application.

Answer (score 0):

For this you would need to have a date field for each row, otherwise there is no way of knowing when a record was inserted.

Comment: i have a row called Year with a lot of files in it.. but i just need to get the current year and 10 years back